# SQL - How can I optimise using SELECT(Min) INNER JOIN in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

I am looking at refactoring some legacy SQL code but not sure how I can refactor this section of code. Does anyone have ideas on what would be the best way to optimise the SELECT (Min) statement below? Although it does work it feels wrong and is slow when running.

Thanks

```
     SELECT   
Id, 
Name,       
            (SELECT MIN(TotalPrice)
                    FROM EventPricing
                    INNER JOIN PriceLevel pl ON (pl.Id = EventPricing.PriceLevelId)
                    INNER JOIN PriceType pt ON (pt.Id = EventPricing.PriceTypeId)
                    WHERE EventId = e.Id 
                    AND pt.PriceTypeKey IN (@AdultPriceTypeKey) 
                    AND pl.PriceLevelKey NOT IN (SELECT [key] from MensHospPriceTypes)) AS FromPrice,
            e.AvailableCapacity
```

Comment: `pt.PriceTypeKey IN (@AdultPriceTypeKey)`? Why not just use `=`?

Comment: @larnu thanks, thats a minor part I'm replacing, it's more the inner joins I'm worried about

Comment: You *might* find better performance if you more the query to the `FROM` in an `APPLY`; the subquery above may well be process once per row, rather than once for the dataset.

Comment: Replacing the `IN` with a `=` won't have performance gains, but it's just an odd choice; `@AdultPriceTypeKey` is a scalar variable so using an `IN` against it, which is meant to be used against a dataset or delimited list of values, doesn't make sense. Unless, by any chance, this is from an SSRS report? If so, what is the datatype of `pt.PriceTypeKey`?

Comment: *it feels wrong*, What's wrong with it? Is it only that it's slow?

Comment: For SQL performance help, we need at a minimum: the full query (it seems you only habe a chunk), the relevant tables and indexes, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. Without this info it's impossible to answer.